# Flutter: How to upload image by WooCommerce rest api?

Tags: wordpress, flutter, woocommerce, file-upload, woocommerce-rest-api

I am using WooCommerce Rest Api in mobile application. Now I want to change the profile picture but I don't know how I should upload an image to Wordpress site through WooCommerce Rest Api, I had already try this but it shows HTTP Error 403:

```
Future<String> uploadImage(File imageFile) async {
    final StringBuffer url =
        new StringBuffer("$serverName/wp-json/wp/v2/media");
    Dio dio = new Dio();

    try {
      FormData formData = FormData.fromMap(
        {"file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(imageFile.path)},
      );
      dio.options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer $token";

      var response = await dio.post(
        url.toString(),
        data: formData,
      );
      var respon = response.data;
      return respon["url"];
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score -1):

your `formData` array must follow the woo-commerce rest API standard.
please find woocommerce rest API documentation for [product properties](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#product-properties) and  [product image properties](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#product-images-properties)

I have PHP code that work with the images. Let me share you if that will be useful for you to convert into flutter code. `images` will an array with `src` as a `url`

```
$data = [
    'name' => 'Premium Quality',
    'type' => 'simple',
    'regular_price' => '21.99',
    'description' => 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.',
    'short_description' => 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.',
    'categories' => [
        [
            'id' => 9
        ],
        [
            'id' => 14
        ]
    ],
    'images' => [
        [
            'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg'
        ],
        [
            'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_back.jpg'
        ]
    ]
];

print_r($woocommerce->post('products', $data));
```